# django-rest-auth get username from rest-auth/user

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios, django-rest-auth

I want to retrieve the user details for displaying the username of the user who is logged-in 
I need to fetch the username from "http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/user/" from django-rest-auth 
I am new to reactjs and tried the authentication which was successfully but couldn't get pass this.

I have tried this so far

```
axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/user/`,
            {
                headers: { 'Authorization': "token " + localStorage.getItem('token') }
            }
        ).then(res => {
            console.log(res)
        }).catch(Error => {
            console.log(Error)
        })
```

which returns the forbidden 403 error;

#### Errors

```
Error: Request failed with status code 403
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:61)
```

Also in the above code I also specified the headers in the following manner **headers: { 'Authorization': "token key_from_DRF " }** but no luck

I have also tried this

```
axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/user/`,
            {
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
            }
        )
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res)
            }).catch(Error => {
                console.log(Error)
            })
```

which returns the same error as before.
How should I execute this request successfully?

Comment: are you getting desired result from same URL in browsable API ?

Comment: since `http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/user/` requires authentication it redirects me to login page  `http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/login/` once that is successful it return the desired data.

Comment: try console.log(token) in axios function, make sure that you passes token

Comment: In the header section try                 headers: { 'Authorization': "Token " + localStorage.getItem('token') }, capital Token instead token

Comment: I have set the 'token' in localStorage in this way; I am certain that passing the token is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The axios POST method is correct, however make sure you passes the token

```
let tokentoserver = localStorage.getItem('token');
console.log(tokentoserver);

axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/user/`,
            {
                headers: { 'Authorization': "Token " tokentoserver }
            }
        ).then(res => {
            console.log(res)
        }).catch(Error => {
            console.log(Error)
        })
```

I have removed the `+`  sign you used to add token together

Comment: It worked I guess but gave me two more errors; (Add a comma between <"Token "> and <tokentoserver>)
the two errors are:-
first

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/user/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field tokentoserver is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.`

second:


`GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/user/ net::ERR_FAILED`
I have set my cors header to `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True`

Comment: I think it is forbidden to call user-details from frontend it can only work in browsable API;

Comment: I dont know how is your view.py,that handles GET request, nothing is forbidden

Comment: I am using the default user model by django-rest-auth just like in this https://github.com/Chinmay-395/django-rest-auth/blob/master/rest_auth/views.py